# The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with paranthesis

Tags: react-native

I tried executing the code. But it shows me error as "Syntax Error. The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with paranthesis." Do i have to cover useState using paranthesis?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';



const DestinationSearch = (props) => {
  
    const [fromText, setFromText]=useState(initalState:'');
    const [destinationText, setTextDestinationText]=useState(initalState:'');

    return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <View>

            <TextInput 
            value={fromText}
            onChangeText={setFromText}
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="From"
            />
            <TextInput 
            value={destinationText}
            onChangeText={setTextDestinationText}
            style={styles.textInput} 
            placeholder="Where to?"
            />
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default DestinationSearch;
```

Answer (score 0):

`initalState:''` is not valid javascript so change these two lines

```
  const [fromText, setFromText] = useState('');
  const [destinationText, setTextDestinationText] = useState('');
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const DestinationSearch = (props) => {
  const [fromText, setFromText] = useState('');
  const [destinationText, setTextDestinationText] = useState('');

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          value={fromText}
          onChangeText={setFromText}
          placeholder="From"
        />
        <TextInput
          value={destinationText}
          onChangeText={setTextDestinationText}
          placeholder="Where to?"
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default DestinationSearch;
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ksav/mad-chip)